# Hibernate JDBCExceptionReporter -> Connection validity, timeout, auto reconnect

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jdbc, jakarta-ee

I have a problem with Hibernate (3.6.0.-Final) in my Java EE application using MySQL and the MySQL Connector/J (official JDBC driver for MySQL).

In my `hibernate.cfg.xml`, I have these lines of code:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydbtest</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">mypassword</property>
        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">20</property>
        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management, in this case 
             the session will be close after each transaction! -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <!-- auto create tables -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">none</property>
        ...
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I changed the value of the property `connection.pool_size` from 1 to 20. I did this because someone was telling me (and I had these problems), that the data was not loaded and an error was thrown with connection pool size. Also,

So I changed the value to 20. but now I get this error:

```
Hibernate: select ...
WARN : org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
ERROR: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - 
       The last packet successfully received from the server was 61.428.729 
       milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 
       61.428. milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 
       'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing 
       connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server 
       configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J 
       connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
```

So what should I do of these possible solutions? What's the best way to solve these JDBC connection issues? I read sth about `c3p0`, but I am new to connection pools. I do not understand the problem: I have a connection pool of 20. So why does it fail? Why throwing an exception and not open a new one?

Thank you a lot in advance & Best Regards.

-- **Update** --

```
<property name=“hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment”>3</property>
<property name=“hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period”>14400</property>
<property name=“hibernate.c3p0.timeout”>25200</property>
<property name=“hibernate.c3p0.max_size”>15</property>
<property name=“hibernate.c3p0.min_size”>3</property>
<property name=“hibernate.c3p0.max_statements”>0</property>
<property name=“hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery”>select 1;</property>
```

-- **Update 2** --

`/etc/my.cnf` file:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Comment: is the problem resolved? What changed made it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This usually happens after some time of inactivity, and MySQL closed the connection in the server side. But the connection in the client side (your application) is still available, so, it ends up being stale.

By using a connection pooling mechanism, it gets in charge of opening/closing the connections when needed, avoiding this kind of problem. One solution, as the error message states, is to use the JDBC option autoReconnect=true in the URL. The other is to configure your connection pooling mechanism to open/test the connection before delivering to your application.

Comment: I updated my question. I found these lines of `c3p0` configuration. Will this also work?

Comment: It helps if your C3P0 timeout is lower than the timeout configured in MySQL server.

Comment: How can I see the default timeout? I updated my question with the content of `my.cnf`.

Comment: So, it should be fine, as the MySQL timeout is 28800 and your C3P0 timeout is 25200. If you have a local development environment, I would change both to 288 and 252 (or any other low value) and test it.

Comment: I integrate it, but now I get these warnings from Tomcat: `WARN : org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory - c3p0 properties is specificed, but could not find org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider from the classpath, these properties are going to be ignored.`

Comment: That means that you are missing the integration component for C3P0 in Hibernate: http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/hibernate/hibernate-c3p0/

Comment: Okay, done and it works! Everything seems to be okay. Thank you.